# Arabic strings not displaying in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using the ResX approach for localized resources in a Xamarin Forms app, the Localizer class below, and three resource files (default en-us, es, ar).

[image]

When the Android device setting is language Spanish, the appropriate translated string is displayed, but when the device setting is Arabic, the default string is displayed. I have set the attribute android:supportsRtl:"true" in app manifest, and am targeting Android 4.2 or higher.

What am I missing?

```
public class Localizer
{
    #region Constructors

    public Localizer()
    {
        RefreshLocale();
        this.Resources = new ResourceManager("MyApp.Resx.AppResources", typeof(Localizer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Methods

    public void RefreshLocale()
    {
        this.Locale = DependencyService.Get<ILocale>().GetCurrent();
    }

    public string Localize(string key)
    {
        return this.Resources.GetString(key, new CultureInfo(this.Locale));
    }

    #endregion Methods

    #region Properties

    public string Locale { get; private set; }

    private ResourceManager Resources;

    #endregion Properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh duh, bitten again. The Build Action was set to None for the Arabic resource file AppResources.ar.resx. This appears to be default Xamarin Studio behavior when adding files with this filetype. Changed the Build Action to EmbeddedResource, rebuilt and deployed, and everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you please share a demo of the project that supports arabic and english at same time. i'm still looking for that demo from weeks ago.

Comment: @Loai Hi, that particular app was done for a client, so I can't post the code directly. I'll see about putting a sample together that gets the main points, give me a few days though.

Comment: yes Please i just need a demo(sample) to how to do that. thank you and i'm waiting for you.

Comment: Did you get something about RTL Arabic in Xamarin forms?