# Xamarin Forms localization strings not showing up on Galaxy s3

Tags: c#, localization, xamarin.forms

I'll make this quick.

I have a Xamarin Forms app, and I am testing the localization feature on a Galaxy S3 device. In the Emulator, the strings change without issues, both in XAML and code behind, when changing the language.

On the Galaxy S3 however, the strings remain in the default language state ( english, although the device in set in another language ).

Any ideas on this behaviour ?

Thank you!

EDIT 1: found a similar post here [How do I get resx files to work with Xamarin.iOS for localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608106/how-do-i-get-resx-files-to-work-with-xamarin-ios-for-localization) but unanswered....

Comment: I have run into issue in the past where the resx file build action defaulted to None when I added the file. Changing the build action to EmbeddedResource solved it for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855717/arabic-strings-not-displaying-in-xamarin-forms-app

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you for the comment. The resx files are set to be EmbeddedResources and the Custom tool is set to PublicResxFileCode as expected ... The emulator displays the strings when changing languages, however a real device does not behave this way ...

Comment: A couple more details might help. What region is the device in? What is the other language besides English? Especially, is it an RTL language? I think I remember having to set a few more things in the Android project properties when I was working to add Arabic support to a Xamarin app developed mainly for the US market.

Comment: The default language is English ( US ), other languages include French, Spanish and Romanian, the device is currently in Romania. I have set up the resx files for english, spanish and romanian. When the device is in English, the default strings appear ( en-US). However if I change the device in Spanish still the default strings appear. In the Emulator all works like a charm ...